# SwiftUI multiple Images tap gesture how to do fullScreenCover on image click

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 images that have onTapGesture . When I tap an image I can see that only the tapped image is clicked however my issue is with **fullScreenCover** . If I click any image it always defaults to the **PersonMain** image view which then goes to **InboxView()** . I have tried putting the fullScreenCover inside the onTapGesture but that does not work . Any suggestions would be great since I'm new to SwiftUI . I've also set the isOpen State to false and the turned it to true on Tap however the first Image View InBoxView() is always the one popping up .

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var isOpen = true
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 7.0) {
            HStack(spacing: 7.0) {
                Image("PersonMain")
                    .padding(.leading, 30.0)
                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    .frame(width:20.0, height: 25.0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Profile")
                    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen,content: {
                        InboxView()
                   })
                
                Image("RankingMain")
                    .padding(.leading, 70.0)
                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    .frame(width: 20.0, height: 25.0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Ranking")
                    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen,content: {
                        SearchView()
                   })
         }
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to use separate states for each of `fullScreenCover`:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var isOpen1 = false
    @State private var isOpen2 = false

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 7.0) {
            HStack(spacing: 7.0) {
                Image("PersonMain")
                    .padding(.leading, 30.0)
                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    .frame(width:20.0, height: 25.0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Profile")
                        self.isOpen1.toggle()
                    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen1, content: {
                        InboxView()
                   })
                
                Image("RankingMain")
                    .padding(.leading, 70.0)
                    .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    .frame(width: 20.0, height: 25.0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Ranking")
                        self.isOpen2.toggle()
                    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isOpen2, content: {
                        SearchView()
                   })
         }
        }
      }
   }
```